# How can I ignore the security warning from the webbrowser?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm developing a tool with WPF in C#. When I load a page in the web browser, I get a security warning from the web browser. Every time I restart the tool I have to reactivate the blocked content.

This is the warning: [image: security warning]

I have to allow the blocked content that the message disappears:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this annoying message without allowing the blocked content every time?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of content are you showing in browser control? Static files or an http address?

Comment: Yes static html files.

Comment: I believe the built-in browser control in WPF uses Internet Explorer. You could try another browser control, like WebView. https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/

Comment: If these are static html files, how come there's active content? This is literally internet explorer which is running, in a thin wrapper.  You could therefore Open your Internet Explorer web browser. Select "Tools" on the menu, then "Internet Options". Select the "Advanced" tab. Find the "Allow active content to run files on My Computer"